# Use anchor or data-filter in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a button in a menu that sorts items listed below it. In this case the button says "news". By using the data-filter attribute or naming it some certain way, can I go to this specific page with this button clicked so that the items are sorted in the way that this button represents?

Can I use anything in  to not only scroll here, but also click the link? Preferably by just using the URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some more information or elaboration will be useful to readers.

Comment: It's really hard to offer any suggestions without a bit more clarity and probably some code!  What server-side language are you using?  Are you doing any of this sorting on the server side or is it all client-side?

Answer (score 1):

In general lines:

1. Define a query string that would represent the desirable action (in your case sort). For instance: `sort=news`
2. On page load - fetch the query string of the page and extract `sort`. ([see MDN for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get))
3. If sort contains a value - trigger the sort functionality

That should do the trick